# AutoReconnect with multiple server uri's

Tags: paho

Consider the scenario where I have below code.

```
MqttConnectOptions connOpt = new MqttConnectOptions();
connOpt.setServerURIs(new String[]{"tcp://localhost:1883", "tcp://some-other-host:1883"});
connOpt.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
client.setCallback( new TemperatureSubscriber() );
client.connect(connOpt);
```

So when I say connect, it connects to localhost.
Then I get connection lost, due to say any reason. So at this point of time, since automaticReconnect is true, will it connect to localhost or some-other-host ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show how to find such answers yourself -

First you visit [the Github repository for Paho source code](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java).

Then you enter `setAutomaticReconnect` into the search field:

[image: browser screenshot 1]

This is of course just the public name. You need to spot the corresponding private member.

In the [MqttConnectOptions.java](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/blob/master/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttConnectOptions.java) with the very simple code you find that member:

```
private boolean automaticReconnect = false;
```

Then you perform another search, this time for the `automaticReconnect` word:

[image: browser screenshot 2]

And that leads you to the hint in the [MqttAsyncClient.java](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/blob/master/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttAsyncClient.java) file -

```
    // Insert our own callback to iterate through the URIs till the connect
    // succeeds
    MqttToken userToken = new MqttToken(getClientId());
    ConnectActionListener connectActionListener = new ConnectActionListener(this, persistence, comms, options,
            userToken, userContext, callback, reconnecting);
    userToken.setActionCallback(connectActionListener);
    userToken.setUserContext(this);
```

Finally, in the [ConnectActionListener.java](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/blob/master/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/internal/ConnectActionListener.java) file you can confirm that the URLs are being tried one after each other:

```
  /**
   * The connect failed, so try the next URI on the list.
   * If there are no more URIs, then fail the overall connect. 
   * 
   * @param token the {@link IMqttToken} from the failed connection attempt
   * @param exception the {@link Throwable} exception from the failed connection attempt
   */
  public void onFailure(IMqttToken token, Throwable exception) {

    int numberOfURIs = comms.getNetworkModules().length;
int index = comms.getNetworkModuleIndex();
    ...
    ...
 comms.setNetworkModuleIndex(index + 1);
```

Comment: thank you for showing how to find the answer, but what is the answer and conclusion from the code?

Comment: "Finally, in the ConnectActionListener.java file you can confirm that the URLs are being tried one after each other"